# Get all Parents, but only one son and one grandson for a condition

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many

I have this structure:

```
Topics.SubTopics.Events
Topics.Users
Users.Topics
```

`Topics` and `Users` is a many-to-many relationship.

I want to retrieve all topics, subtopics and events where a `PremiereDateTimeInUtc` (property of an event) is `equal or greater then yesterday` and where the `Topics.Users.Id == userId`. But only 1 event should be retrieved (the first one from yesterday) for each topic. And only the subtopic which is the parent of the event. But Topic must all be returned even the ones which don't have and subtopic and event.

I tried this so far:

```
return context.Topics
.Include(
    t => t.SubTopics.Select(
        s => s.Events
        .Any(e => e.PremiereDateTimeInUtc >= DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1))
    )
)
.Where(t => t.Users.Any(u => u.Id == userId)).ToList();
```

But this doesn't work. I get this exception: "The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.
Parameter name: path".

Comment: first problem: that's not what `Include` is for: all it does is list child tables who's *columns* are loaded with the initial query. It doesn't participate in the LINQ filtering at all.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield which method should i look into/use then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var yesterday =DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);

var events = context.Events.Where(x=>x.PremiereDateTimeInUtc>=yesterday)
    .GroupBy(x=>x.Subtopic.TopicId, (k,g)=>new{
        TopicId=k,
        Event=g.OrderBy(e=>e.PremiereDateTimeInUtc).FirstOrDefault()
    });

var topics = context.Topics
    .Where(t=>t.Users.Any(u=>u.Id==userId))
    .GroupJoin(events, t=>t.Id, e=>e.TopicId,(t,g)=>new{
        Topic=t,
        FirstEvent=g.FirstOrDefault(),
        Subtopic=g.FirstOrDefault().Subtopic
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean with single query? This actually IS a single query. "topics" is the single query and the one is being executed. I split "events" part just for readability, but it's not being executed alone. Both queries get composed and all will be executed when you enumerate topics.

Comment: Oh great then... Didn't get that. Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to retrieve this in a non-anonymous object? Or is this the only way of doing this and has to be converted later?

Comment: You can't retrieve this as graph, because you require much more than navigating properties. But once you have got the result, you can process it and build the structure you want. If this isn't enough for you may be you can post some more info in the question and may be we could provide an answer suited to you

Comment: It's going in the right direction. I think that it works fine so far, there is just something missing still. I get all topics now instead of only the ones to which an user is subscribed. It may be that i'm missing a `.Where()`? This is due to my mistake, i didn't mention this in my question, i have updated the question right now, all i have added to the question was this: "and where the `TvShows.Users.Id == userId`". Else it's working perfect.

Comment: What is TvShows? And how it's related to the rest of entities?

Comment: It's Topics and not TvShows, sorry my mistake, i copied/pasted wrong. :/

Comment: This was giving me headaches for days. I will do some more such queries for training, have to learn and understand how this is done. Will study it. Thank you very much! Works like a charm. :)

Comment: If it's not too much to ask... What would be the shortest code to convert this anonymous object into `Topics.SubTopics.Events`?

Comment: Must i do this with loops or is there a method/s which can do this with less code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102838/discussion-between-tede24-and-jo-smo).

Comment: I think there is no magic here. You could loop result and attach sub objects to parents.

Comment: Another question... Why does each Topic in the anonymous object have all it's SubTopic's and Event's?  Is it possible to get only the ones which are needed? I don't see any Include() anywhere, that's what bugs me.

Comment: Never mind... They get disposed after the context is closed. Everything is fine. Just the FirstEvent has SubTopic included. But i will set it to null before it's assigned to my object. I will leave this comment here for me, just in case in the future i would wonder about the same problem. :D

Comment: Dudable lazy loading or query AsNoTrack() so EF won't load collections when navigating to them.

Comment: Thank you. Will look into it.

Comment: I would ask a new question for this, as it's out of original question, and other people may find it useful. Regards

Comment: I solved it. Anyways, i already figured it out. The problem was, that i calculated the value for Skip() wrong. And Needed to order the collection before using Skip().